# Best Way to Grab Post ID from Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, loop

I'm currently using loop_end to hook my plugin and get the post id from a page.  This works great, except that it's also displaying my plugin in the recent posts widget which I don't want.

Is there a better way to do this so that it ONLY displays on page content and not widgets?

Answer (score 0):

`loop_end` hook is passing `WP_Query` object as argument. You can use `is_main_query()` method on that object (don't confuse with function of same name) and it will only be true for main query and not secondary ones.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the ID during `template_redirect` before any widget has been called:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){
    $my_plugin = new My_Plugin;
    $my_plugin->get_id();
});

class My_Plugin
{
    protected $post_id;

    public function get_id()
    {
        if ( is_page() )
            $this->post_id = get_the_ID();
    }
}
```

Now you can use `$post_id` in later methods of the same class.